# Jquery dialog resize before opening but dialog opens with previous width-height

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using jquery dialog to open a screen when the buttons clicked on the sidebar.
Basically, when clicked buton, following codes run:

```
resizeDialog();
$("#dashboardContainer").dialog("open");
```

```
function resizeDialog() {
    var relativeDiv, relativeHeight, relativeWidth, relativeMy;

    if(myData.opening_type == 'full') {
        relativeDiv = '#sContainer';
        relativeWidth = '328';
        relativeMy = 'left top';

    } else {
        relativeDiv = '#cContainer';
        relativeMy = 'right top';

        var mqDesktop2 = window.matchMedia( "(min-width : 1500px) and (max-width : 1750px)" );
        var mqMobile = window.matchMedia( "(min-width:700px) and (max-width: 1500px)" );

        if(mqMobile.matches) {
            relativeWidth = '648';

        } else if(mqDesktop2.matches) {
            relativeWidth = '968';

        } else {
            relativeWidth = '1320';
        };
    }
    relativeHeight =  $(window).height() - ($("#cContainer").offset().top) - 20;

    $("#myDialog")
        .dialog( "option", "height", relativeHeight)
        .dialog( "option", "width", relativeWidth)
        .dialog( "option", "position", { my: relativeMy, at: "right top", of: relativeDiv, } );
}
```

But, when i frequently(one after another) click on the buttons, dialog  opens with its previous size. When i add a timeout before opening dialog, it runs. But i don't want to add a timeout because dialog has to be opened immediately. Is there any other solutions that u can suggest?

Comment: Unclear why you believe the dialog would be resized. Unsure what "button" you are referring to. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Every button in sidebar opens dialog with different width & height. Buttons are just buttons, they all have onclick event, every onclick opens dialog and puts a different iframe in it. But before open dialog when i give height-width it works but if i clicked frequently(which means frequently close-open dialog) dialog opens with previous width-height.

Comment: I do not see these buttons in your example. Without a proper example it will be difficult for people to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to replicate the issue as you described it. I created the following test.

```js
$(function() {
  function resizeDialog(dlg, w, h, cb) {
    dlg.dialog("option", {
      height: h,
      width: w
    });
    if (cb != undefined) {
      cb();
    }
  }
  $("[id^='dialog']").dialog({
    autoOpen: false
  });
  resizeDialog($("#dialog-1"), 200, 320, function() {
    $("#dialog-1").dialog("open");
  });
  resizeDialog($("#dialog-2"), 120, 120);
  $("#dialog-2").dialog("option", "position", {
    my: "left top",
    at: "left+10 top+10",
    of: window
  }).dialog("open");
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dialog-1" title="Basic dialog 1">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
<div id="dialog-2" title="Basic dialog 2">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

I am able to resize them and `open` them in a similar manner as your script. I would add some checks to ensure that you're getting the relative values you are expecting.